# Selenium Webdriver requests a different url from the one set

Tags: python, selenium

After an update in selenium and visual studio I have the following problem. I try to get a url for example
thestore = "http://shop.oki.gr/shop/store/diathesimotita_new.asp" and instead I have a window opened with

http://www.puttop.top/object.php?u=http://shop.oki.gr/shop/store/customerauthenticateform.asp?redirectUrl=http://shop.oki.gr/shop/store/diathesimotita_new.asp&title=Login%20Page

which of course is not working.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory":  downloads_path,
                                              "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
                                              "download.prompt_for_download": False,
                                              "directory_upgrade": True,
                                              "safebrowsing.enabled": True})
    

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
    
    thestore = "http://shop.oki.gr/shop/store/diathesimotita_new.asp"
    browser.get(thestore)
```

The initial url is opening from other pc normally..
What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I cant open either of these but it seems like its redirecting you to a login page first
I have a couple programs that do something similar and I keep a function that login for me on hand, then I get the original url again